# How to decrease sent byte size in a .NET web request

Tags: .net, vb.net, fiddler

I have been using fiddler and see that my sent request byte size is rather large compared to the size of the page being received. This has been causing speed issues for users that have low upload speeds.

Fiddler Details:

```
Bytes Sent:      62,988     (headers:1,299; body:61,689)
Bytes Received:  186,510        (headers:387; body:186,123)
```

Our website uses [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). Is there a way to determine why so much is being sent in a request and what it is?

Comment: Well, what data is being sent up?

Comment: Uh, are you sure that "Bytes Sent" is bytes from the server to the client and not the other way around?

Comment: Use Fiddler and look at the request. What is so big there?

Answer (score 2):

If it's ASP.NET, much of the posted data is probably [View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - i.e. the hidden `__VIEWSTATE` form field, used to keep the values for controls between postbacks.  You can disable view state at the [control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) level, if you can live with the consequences, to reduce this overhead.